# Get the Argentinian resident permit

Tags: eu-citizens, resident-permit, argentina, german-citizens

I'm from Germany but I have lived in Argentina for a year. I currently use a tourist visa for that, leaving and returning to Argentina every 3 months and don't work here.

I don't want to work here. I work in Germany from time to time and live from that money in Argentina.

I want to

- live in Argentina
- have the possibilities to buy property
- come and go over the border as I like
- have the right to stay permanently

What possibilities do I have to get a resident permit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two possible ways to stay long-term in Argentina – as a Permanent Resident or a Temporary Resident and it seems that it's **not** an easy and fast process, involving much paperwork:

> - Proof of identity: valid identity card or passport with at least 6 months remaining and a complete set of photocopies (including blank
>     pages).
> - Proof of entry: entrance stamp affixed to the country travel document or immigration card.
> - Birth certificate: translated to Spanish and legalized by the Argentine Consulate.
> - Criminal record certificate: issued by the country where the the last 5 (five) years were spent prior to entry.
> - Argentine criminal record certificate: Criminal record issued by the Argentine Federal Police (Azopardo 620. Buenos Aires).
> - Two color photos (4×4)
> - Employment contract: Signed employment contract from a business or place of work registered with the Argentine consulate. See the
>     department of immigration for more details/
> - Application fee: AR $600
>
> All foreign language documents must be translated into Spanish by a
>   National Public Translator certified by the Association of Translators
>   (Corrientes 1834. Buenos Aires. Tel: 4373-7173). Original language
>   copies must be submitted along with their translations. The Department
>   of Immigration may request, if deemed necessary, additional
>   documentation.

As you don't work in Argentina, you can apply for Financier visa:

> This is a broad-based and flexible visa and merely requires proof that
>   a guaranteed minimum monthly income of 8,500 Argentine pesos (ARS) or
>   2,200 USD can be paid into an Argentinean bank account. The
>   immigration authorities will require you to prove that this income
>   will continue once you have moved to Argentina. Income from
>   investments, annuities and dividends from a business are all
>   acceptable.

If you don't speak Spanish fluently, it's advisable to find someone to help you - an agency or at least a friend.

For more information see:

- http://www.expatarrivals.com/argentina/visas-for-argentina
- http://www.expatarrivals.com/article/getting-and-applying-for-permanent-residency-in-argentina
- http://argentina.angloinfo.com/moving/residency/permanent-residency/
- http://enterbuenosaires.com/get-argentinian-residency/

Answer (score 0):

I know that for Americans you have to provide proof that you have an income of at least $1000/month or that you have a job in Argentina. If you want a job and you speak English it really won't be hard. I knew Americans/Canadians that got jobs with real estate offices and software developers simply because they spoke English. The company just paid them in cash under the table.

You're going to want to fill out the paperwork to get what is called "Documento Nacional de Identificación de Extranjero" or "DNI de Extranjero". I believe you're going to have to go to a police station to fill out the paperwork. It is the Argentine national identification card. If you're a foreigner then they will simply mark "Extranjero" on your card. You're also going to need an Argentina address. This is where they are going to send the card once you are approved and this is the address that will appear on your ID. They will run a background check in your home country to make sure that you're not a criminal or anything like that. I was surprised at how fast the process went for some of my friends.

I'm not sure if you have to pay a fee to get the paperwork started, but if you have access to Euros then it should be really cheap for you.

Comment: But I don't want to work in Argentina. :)

Comment: @juergend You don't have to work as long as you can show that you're you have a sustainable cashflow of about $1k/month. I doubt they will let you stay permanently if you have no job and no money. You've been there for a year so I image you've been doing something for money. Show them that.